# DockerHub set tag alias in automated build

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm using Docker Hub's automated build system to build a docker image. That image comes in two flavors (Debian jessie and wheezy based). I like to have speaking tags for both of those (`:jessie` and `:wheezy`) but would also like to have a `:latest` tag pointing to the `:jessie` flavor.

For now I simply duplicated the jessie line in the automated build config:

[image: docker settings]

But this seems to actually build the image twice. What I would need is a way to specify a tag alias, but I am not sure if that's possible. And if so how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently not possible to have more than one docker tag name by build. Duplicating the build is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tags regexp [image: regexp]

Look at the last tag that gets created.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I am not using any git tags. I only have one branch and two Dockerfiles. In my screenshot I want to get rid of the third line and instead configure the first to create two docker tags: :jessie and :latest

Comment: Ok sorry, I understand now what you really meant. It's not currently possible on docker hub, you can't have one build to create 2 tags.

Comment: I feared so. Can you make that an answer?